# how to create an empty 2 d list or list of lists of a size in megabytes.

Tags: python, list

how to create an empty 2 d list or list of lists of a size in megabytes. main purpose is it can store data in Mbs but while iterating it should not process empty sub sub lists.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean with "*of a size in megabytes*"?

Comment: In Python you do not need to pre-allocate memory for a list when you define it. Or do you want to define a large empty structure like `[[],[],[]]`...

Comment: if your data is numeric, I would suggest [numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) for their better performance, and lower memory overhead. Assigning `nan` to values not yet written is a good way of representing data currently still missing

Comment: actually I am trying to fetch a data from a log file. and storing the intermediate data in a list of lists. when the input file is smaller, program runs fine but when the input file is of a bigger size, it doesn't show any data in that list. when I am storing this intermediate data in a file, program runs fine, but i want to store data in the list itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a data structure like this: `[[], [], []]`, ultimately. Let's call that final data structure `master`. There are two ways to interpret your question, then:

1) the "size" of just `master` itself (and not the objects to which it refers) should be *n* megabytes.

2) the size of `master` plus the size of every object contained within should be *n* megabytes.

These are two slightly different problems. If you just wanted to add empty lists to `master` until the size of **`master`** reached *n* MB, then you could do something like this.

```
def init_empty_array(mb):
    byte = mb*(10**6)
    master = []
    size = getsizeof(master)
    while size < byte:
        master.append([])
        size = getsizeof(master)
    return master
```

[`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) returns the size of an object in bytes, so that's why we convert the passed `mb` (megabytes) parameter to bytes. Then we create an empty, "master" list and grab its size (which is 64 bytes in Python). After that, we just append to `master` empty lists until we reach the desired size. You could really just initiate `size` as 64 and then add 8 for each additional list, instead of using `sys.getsizeof`.

Notice, however, that the ultimate size of `master` likely will not correspond with the size you would expect from appending *k* lists to `master`. That's because `sys.getsizeof` only measures the size of `master` itself, and not the lists contained therein. Consider this:

```
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> getsizeof([])
64
>>> getsizeof([[]])
72
```

Well, look at that. The size, in bytes, of `[]` (an empty list) is 64 bytes. If we nest an empty list inside of a formerly-empty list, call the outer list `arr`, then the size of `arr` becomes 72. Each additional object (`str`, `list`, `set`, etc.) added to `arr` adds 8 bytes to the size of `arr`. But there's still technically an empty list inside of `[[]]`, right? It's up to you whether you want to account for the size (64 bytes) of each empty list inside your master list.

To get both the size of `master` and the objects contained within, you can try something like this:

```
def init_empty_array(mb):
    byte = mb*(10**6)
    master = []
    size = 64
    while size < byte:
        master.append([])
        size += 64 + 8
    return master
```

We add 64 bytes for the additional list, and 8 for the additional size added to `master` from that list.

Please note that, depending on how many megabytes you pass (e.g. 2.53 versus 2.0), your final `master` list may or may not be *exactly* the size of `mb` that you pass (that's because we can't append a fraction of a list; it's either 64 bytes or nothing).

Depending on whether `mb` is a strict upper or lower limit, you can adjust where `master`'s size falls (i.e. add some modular arithmetic in there to find the maximum or minimum number of lists for a given number of megabytes).

And, suppose you wanted to fill a list with *whatever* until its size reached *n* MB. You could use the recursive memory footprint function [here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) to measure the size of everything in that list (whether the objects within are `str`, `set`, `list`, `dict`, or `tuple`, or any combination of those classes).

As you can see, there's lots of room above for your own interpretation and tweaking, but this should give you a good start.

Comment: thanks, actually I am trying to fetch a data from a log file. and storing the intermediate data in a list of lists. when the input file is smaller, program runs fine but when the input file is of a bigger size, it doesn't show any data in that list. when I am storing this intermediate data in a file, program runs fine, but i want to store data in the list itself.